# Django Nested Serializer not serializing the foreign key object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I know that this question has been asked before, but I've tried so many different solutions and just cannot seem to get it to work. All I am attempting to do is display one object within another on an api call. In this simple example, lets say that I have an artist object and a track object. When I serialize the track object, I would like for the artist object that it refers to using a foreign key to be displayed.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Artist' )
    track_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Artist
        fields = '__all__'



class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Track
        fields = ('id', 'track_name', 'artist')
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Whats is the data you are getting from the ``TrackSerializer``?

Comment: I tested it and your code was working!

Comment: Okay, so I got it figured out. The issue was that I needed different serializers depending on whether or not it was a POST or a GET request. For GET, the code I had worked. However, when I tried to do a POST request, it was making me create a new artist instead of just linking with a pre-existing one. So I just wrote a post specific serializer. Thank you for the help!